# Exclude Certain Database Objects from the Build Depending on Configuration Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database project in Visual Studio 2012 with SSDT (latest as of this writing). In the database project, I have a schema called "**UNITTEST**" which contains tons of stored procedures that create, destroy, and provide other helper functionality for the unit tests. We do this because it gives us the ability to control our test data centrally rather than inside each unit test.  Now that's fine and all however, I don't want to publish this schema or any of the objects inside of this schema to production.

So my question.. Is there a way to stop SSDT/VS2012 from including the UNITTEST schema in the production build deployment script?

I'm thinking there should be a way to do it depending on the solution configuration settings and publish profiles. If my configuration is set to "Release" then I want the build to perform a bit differently.

Builds are very new to me. I found this question: **[build-different-scripts-depending-on-build-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117258/sql-database-project-build-different-scripts-depending-on-build-configuration)** but I can't seem to get the answer to fulfill my problem. This question also doesn't help although it's very similar: **[bind-the-deploy-and-publish-destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070118/msbuild-sql-server-database-project-bind-the-deploy-and-publish-desination-to)**.

Is anyone else managing something like this? The other developers in my team are just modifying the published script to remove these objects but I HATE manual work, there HAS to be a solution! :)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial/Composite projects might be useful here. Main project contains all of your necessary DB objects for your apps to run. The partial project references the main project, but then contains all of the "Test" code.

Here are a couple of options from Jamie Thomson:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/03/10/deployment-of-client-specific-database-code-using-ssdt.aspx --This may be the simplest way to handle this

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/01/01/implementing-sql-server-solutions-using-visual-studio-2010-database-projects-a-compendium-of-project-experiences.aspx --Lots of good information in this post and most of it also applies to SSDT SQL Projects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193415.aspx - Composite projects for larger DBs. This could potentially work for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

One of my schemas references a lot of `sys.*` objects which created a lot of errors in the build.  I created another project in the solution and moved that schema to the new project.

Luckily you can build and publish at the project level.

This allows me to keep the other schema in change control at least.

(It may also help to set the Properties on the SQL files to **`Build Action`: None**)